# Non empty collections always marked dirty after Hibernate merge of detached object

Tags: java, hibernate

I wasn't expecting this behaviour and unsure whether it's a bug or by design.

We have a parent object with a List of child objects.  It's a uni-directional relationship using a join table.  If a client requests a parent object merge, Hibernate *increments the version of the parent object even though none of its details have changed*.  I wasn't expecting the parent object version to change as, logically, the parent object is exactly the same.  Does anyone have an explanation?

Note 1: it's due to the collection being marked as dirty in the flush, however this doesn't happen if the collection is empty or the parent object doesn't contain a collection

Note 2: very similar to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3007 which has been auto closed due to inactivity

Note 3: using Hibernate 4.3.7.Final, but tested same behaviour in Hibernate 3

**Test to reproduce**

```
@Test
public void testCreateAndUpdate() throws Exception {

    // POST from client - note: deptartment object containing a single empty employee 
    String jsonFromClient = "{\"employees\":[{}]}";
    Department department = mapper.readValue(jsonFromClient, Department.class);

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.persist(department);
    tx.commit();

    // simulates sending it back to client
    String jsonToClient = mapper.writeValueAsString(department);
    System.out.println(jsonToClient);   // {"id":1,"version":0,"employees":[{"id":1,"version":0}]}

    // PUT from client, but nothing has actually changed
    jsonFromClient = jsonToClient;
    department = mapper.readValue(jsonFromClient, Department.class);

    // new session emulates the client updating the Department
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    department = (Department) session.merge(department);
    tx.commit();

    // NOTE: PARENT VERSION INCREMENTED!!
    jsonToClient = mapper.writeValueAsString(department);
    System.out.println(jsonToClient);  // {"id":1,"version":1,"employees":[{"id":1,"version":0}]}

}
```

**Department.java**

```
@Entity
public class Department {
private Long id;
private Long version;
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();


@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() { return id; }

public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

@Version
public Long getVersion() { return version; }

public void setVersion(Long version) { this.version = version; }

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="DEPARTMENT_EMPLOYEE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="DEPARTMENT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="EMPLOYEE_ID"))
public List<Employee> getEmployees() { return employees; }

public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) { this.employees = employees; }

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Department)) return false;

    Department that = (Department) o;

    //if (employees != null ? !employees.equals(that.employees) : that.employees != null) return false;
    if (!id.equals(that.id)) return false;
    if (!version.equals(that.version)) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + version.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + (employees != null ? employees.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}

}
```

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

private Long id;
private Long version;


@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() { return id; }

public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

@Version
public Long getVersion() { return version; }

public void setVersion(Long version) { this.version = version; }

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Employee)) return false;

    Employee employee = (Employee) o;

    if (!id.equals(employee.id)) return false;
    if (!version.equals(employee.version)) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + version.hashCode();
    return result;
}

}
```

Comment: ages old a no answer !?